# HQL: how to find item in a subcollection by id

Tags: java, hql, jpql

I'm trying to find the number of Events that have a given Cluster as member. I have the cluster id. (Event to Cluster is a ManyToMany.)

I have an HQL query like this:

```
select count(*) from Event e join e.clusters c where :id in (c.id)
```

I've also tried to put a subselect in the "in" part, but no luck.

Is there a way to do this in HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct e.id) 
from Event e join e.clusters c 
where c.id = :id
```

Comment: Thanks, that works (with minor change). HQL doesn't want parens around the argument to "distinct", so should just be: select count(distinct e.id)